# How to make MS Access open hyperlinks in existing IE context

Tags: internet-explorer, ms-access

I have a MS Access 2007 database where one field is a hyperlink to a URL on a website that requires authentication. When the hyperlink is opened from MS Access, Internet Explorer requires the user to reauthenticate everytime the hyperlink is open, even if the user s already logged into the website.

When the same hyperlink is opened from MS Outlook 2007 or from the Run Dialog in the Start Menu, and the user is already logged into the website, the hyperlink is opened as expected without forcing the user to reauthenticate. Why is MS Access 2007 behaving differently than MS Outlook 2007, and (in a form) how can I work around this?

Comment: Not sure its relevant but what type of authentication are you talking about? e.g. Session cookie based or Windows Auth? You could use process explorer to look at the IE processes spawned by Access and those that work as you want and see if there is anything different about them (e.g. command line arguments)

Comment: My guess is that Access is for some reason starting a new session on the web server whereas Outlook does not. I can't explain the reason why this would be. If this is actually the case then the website in question must be programmed to require a login every time a new session is started. Some websites allow logins to be preserved using cookies but apparently this one does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. In the VBA code for the database I added the following functions:

```
Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, _
    ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, _
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Public Function OpenURL(theURL as String)
    ShellExecute Screen.ActiveForm.hWnd, "open", theURL, "", "", vbNormalFocus
End Function
```

In my form code, I simply call OpenURL as follows:

```
OpenURL HyperlinkPart(Me![URL], acFullAddress)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't find this to be an acceptable solution because it requires a lot of additional effort to make it behave like a hyperlink. I can't understand why Microsoft made Access handle links differently from *every other Office application!*

Comment: I wouldn't say it requires 'a lot' of additional effort, assuming you are displaying the hyperlink on a form you just format the textbox to look like a hyperlink and add the `OpenURL` call to the `OnClick` event, after that it looks after itself. You don't get the right-click features of a hyperlink but when do you really need those? +1 from me.